# Python: Group and count unique variables based on multiple grouping without recount

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I have a Dataframe with 3 columns:

```
ID  Round  Investor
X   1      A
X   2      A
X   2      B
X   3      A
Y   1      A
Y   1      B
Y   1      C
Y   2      B
Y   2      D
```

And want to count the number of unique investors for each round for each ID. But I dont want it to recount the investor if it has been in the previous round. The code I am using is:

`print(df.groupby(['ID', 'Round'])['Investor'].nunique())`

Which results in:

```
ID  Round  Unique Investor
X   1      1
    2      2
    2      2
    3      1
Y   1      3
    1      3
    1      3
    2      2
    2      2
```

But I dont what it to count when an investor have invested in a earlier round for the same ID:

```
ID  Round  Unique Investor
X   1      1
    2      1
    2      1
    3      0
Y   1      3
    1      3
    1      3
    2      1
    2      1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a helper column `Investor2` which is grouped under `ID` and dropped duplicates within the same `ID` with [`Series.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html)

Then, group by `ID` and `Round` as you did before on this `Investor2` column with [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) and [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html), as follows:

```
df['Unique Investor'] = (
    df.assign(Investor2=df.groupby('ID')['Investor'].apply(pd.Series.drop_duplicates).droplevel(0))
      .groupby(['ID', 'Round'])['Investor2'].transform('nunique')
    )
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  ID  Round Investor  Unique Investor
0  X      1        A                1
1  X      2        A                1
2  X      2        B                1
3  X      3        A                0
4  Y      1        A                3
5  Y      1        B                3
6  Y      1        C                3
7  Y      2        B                1
8  Y      2        D                1
```

Comment: Cheers mate! That did the trick, you dont happend to know a quick way to get the accumulated number of unique investors while you are still at it? So we get: Acc_unique_investor = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]

Comment: @Hassan33  That's an interesting new question. I think the difficult part is at the multiple entries within the same Round while we need to count only once for each Round for the repeating values.

Comment: @Hassan33  For your new question, actually it's very similar to the one here.  Try: `(df.assign(unique_investor2=df.groupby(['ID', 'Round'])['Unique Investor'].apply(pd.Series.drop_duplicates).droplevel([0,1]))
   .groupby('ID')['unique_investor2'].cumsum().ffill(downcast='infer')
)`

Comment: thanks a lot, I did an alternative solution but yours is way simpler and quicker

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to drop the duplicates, based on 'ID' and Investor, groupby ID and Round to get number of uniques, and merge the result back to the main dataframe:

```py
dups = ['ID', 'Investor']

group = ['ID', 'Round']

mapping = (df.drop_duplicates(subset = dups)
             .groupby(group)
             .Investor
             .nunique()
          )

(df.filter(group)
   .merge(mapping, left_on = group, 
          right_index = True, how = 'left')
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)

  ID  Round  Investor
0  X      1         1
1  X      2         1
2  X      2         1
3  X      3         0
4  Y      1         3
5  Y      1         3
6  Y      1         3
7  Y      2         1
8  Y      2         1
```